# How can I calculate a border/stroke added to a triangle, given the triangles vectors and the stroke width?

Tags: javascript, c++, webgl, trigonometry

I have a single set of triangle coordinates. One vector for each three points. In the image bellow this triangle is the `thin yellow` one.  I need to add a `stroke` or `border` to this triangle that protrudes both inwards and outwards, centered to the original yellow triangle lines.

Therefore, given the original set of three triangle `vector` coordinates and the stroke/border `width`, how can I calculate the `vector` coordinates for the outer and inner edges of the `black` (stroke/border) triangle?

The `red` dots in the image indicate the points I need to calculate.

The triangle can be scaled by either width or height and I need the black stroke/border to always remain at a constant given width.

Although I need to implement this separately in both `C++` and `javascript` for `WebGL`, it is only really the mathematical formulas that I need.

If we imagine the `variables` I have visualized in `javascript` with the top-left point of the original triangles bounding box being `(0,0)` then we get the following:

```
var width = 300;
var height = 200;
var strokeWidth = 20;
var V1 = {x: 0, y: height};
var V2 = {x: width, y: height};
var V3 = {x: width / 2, y: 0);
```

From that, i need to calculate all six red points.  Thanks in advance for any help.

[image]

Comment: You might find [this page useful](http://labs.hyperandroid.com/efficient-webgl-stroking).

Answer (score 2):

When you define your vertex positions relative to the center you can just get the direction by normalizing them, then multiply the direction by your stroke width and add/subtract the result to your vertices, in glsl that would be:

```
float strokeWidth = 10.;
vec2 vdir = normalize(vertexPosition);
vec2 outer = vertexPosition + vdir * strokeWidth;
vec2 inner = vertexPosition - vdir * strokeWidth;
```

In JS without any math library it would look like this:

```js
function Point(x,y){this.x = x, this.y = y}
var strokeWidth = 20;
var V1 = new Point(-100,50);
var V2 = new Point(100,50);
var V3 = new Point(0, -100);

var ctx = triangle.getContext("2d"), ctxRect = ctx.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

function drawPoints () {
ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctxRect.width,ctxRect.height);

// draw initial points
ctx.strokeStyle = ctx.fillStyle = "#fa0";
ctx.fillRect(V1.x+ctxRect.width / 2,V1.y+ctxRect.height / 2,5,5);
ctx.fillRect(V2.x+ctxRect.width / 2,V2.y+ctxRect.height / 2,5,5);
ctx.fillRect(V3.x+ctxRect.width / 2,V3.y+ctxRect.height / 2,5,5);
// draw triangle lines
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(V1.x+ctxRect.width / 2+2,V1.y+ctxRect.height / 2+2);
ctx.lineTo(V2.x+ctxRect.width / 2+2,V2.y+ctxRect.height / 2+2);
ctx.lineTo(V3.x+ctxRect.width / 2+2,V3.y+ctxRect.height / 2+2);
ctx.lineTo(V1.x+ctxRect.width / 2+2,V1.y+ctxRect.height / 2+2);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();

// get direction
var len = Math.sqrt(V1.x*V1.x+V1.y*V1.y);
var dx = V1.x / len, dy = V1.y / len;
var V1outer = new Point(V1.x + dx * strokeWidth, V1.y + dy * strokeWidth);
var V1inner = new Point(V1.x - dx * strokeWidth, V1.y - dy * strokeWidth);
console.log(V1outer);
len = Math.sqrt(V2.x*V2.x+V2.y*V2.y);
dx = V2.x / len, dy = V2.y / len;
var V2outer = new Point(V2.x + dx * strokeWidth, V2.y + dy * strokeWidth);
var V2inner = new Point(V2.x - dx * strokeWidth, V2.y - dy * strokeWidth);

len = Math.sqrt(V3.x*V3.x+V3.y*V3.y);
dx = V3.x / len, dy = V3.y / len;
var V3outer = new Point(V3.x + dx * strokeWidth, V3.y + dy * strokeWidth);
var V3inner = new Point(V3.x - dx * strokeWidth, V3.y - dy * strokeWidth);

ctx.strokeStyle = ctx.fillStyle = "#F00";
ctx.fillRect(V1outer.x+ctxRect.width / 2, V1outer.y+ctxRect.height / 2, 5,5);
ctx.fillRect(V2outer.x+ctxRect.width / 2, V2outer.y+ctxRect.height / 2, 5,5);
ctx.fillRect(V3outer.x+ctxRect.width / 2, V3outer.y+ctxRect.height / 2, 5,5);

// draw triangle lines
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(V1outer.x+ctxRect.width / 2+2,V1outer.y+ctxRect.height / 2+2);
ctx.lineTo(V2outer.x+ctxRect.width / 2+2,V2outer.y+ctxRect.height / 2+2);
ctx.lineTo(V3outer.x+ctxRect.width / 2+2,V3outer.y+ctxRect.height / 2+2);
ctx.lineTo(V1outer.x+ctxRect.width / 2+2,V1outer.y+ctxRect.height / 2+2);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
  
ctx.strokeStyle = ctx.fillStyle = "#0F0";
ctx.fillRect(V1inner.x+ctxRect.width / 2, V1inner.y+ctxRect.height / 2, 5,5);
ctx.fillRect(V2inner.x+ctxRect.width / 2, V2inner.y+ctxRect.height / 2, 5,5);
ctx.fillRect(V3inner.x+ctxRect.width / 2, V3inner.y+ctxRect.height / 2, 5,5);

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(V1inner.x+ctxRect.width / 2+2,V1inner.y+ctxRect.height / 2+2);
ctx.lineTo(V2inner.x+ctxRect.width / 2+2,V2inner.y+ctxRect.height / 2+2);
ctx.lineTo(V3inner.x+ctxRect.width / 2+2,V3inner.y+ctxRect.height / 2+2);
ctx.lineTo(V1inner.x+ctxRect.width / 2+2,V1inner.y+ctxRect.height / 2+2);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();

}
drawPoints();
strokeInput.oninput = function () {strokeWidth = this.value; drawPoints()}
```

```css
#triangle { border: 1px dashed black; }
```

```html
<label>Stroke Width: <input id="strokeInput" type="range" min="0" max="50" value="20"/></label><br/>
<canvas id="triangle" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: that example doesn't really work. Try setting your `V1.x` to `-10` and `V2.x` to `10` and you'll see. I'm guessing you want to use the normal of each line to generate a new line and intersect it with each of the joining lines?

Comment: An excellent and thorough answer but gman is correct.  Close but no cigar i'm afraid. Thanks for the well written answer however.

Comment: @gordyr hi did you find the solution , i'am working software-renderer from scratch 
and now i'am stuck because of this traingle border problem , help plz :)